I want to take the object created with geo node to the origin point of another object
I am creating a mesh circle with Geo Nodes. Let's say this circle(object A)6 is at this location:
x:50
y:100
z:100
and another object (Object B) is at the following location for example:
x:100
y:150
z:150
I want to create "Object A" at the location of Object B every time.

What is your question and what have you got so far (image of your geonodes)? See: How do I ask a good question.

(Using Blender 4.2.0)

1. Object "A" is the default cube located at (5,10,10) in world coordinates. The GeometryNodes modifier "Draw a Circle" is attached to it. As its input Geometry is not used, only its origin is displayed as an orange dot in the 3D Viewport.
2. Object "B" is an icosphere located at (10,15,15) in world coordinates.
3. The Location of object "B" is recovered inside object "A" GeometryNodes modifier using an Object Info node. By setting its Transform Space to Relative, the output Location is (10,15,15)-(5,10,10)=(5,5,5), i.e. the vector connecting the origin of "A" to the origin of "B".
4. It is to notice that the origin of the circle generated by the Mesh Circle node is located at the origin of object "A". Consequently, using a Transform Geometry node with Translation set to the vector output at step 3 moves the circle vertices (beware, not its origin) around the origin of object "B".
NB: A GeometryNodes modifier is not affecting the origin of the object to which it is attached. It is only modifying vertices position. It behaves like modifications in Edit Mode. The origin of an object is modified only in Object Mode.

There are two possible ways to interpret your scenario: you create a Mesh Circle within Geometry Nodes, and some base object with the GN modifier is at (50, 100, 100). Then initially the Mesh Circle will have its center globally at these coordinates, the origin of the base object because the origin is the local (0, 0, 0). Or you have a mesh circle object as base object located at (50, 100, 100) and you add a GN modifier to it and want to move the original circle mesh with GN.
And in both cases you could read the (Relative) Location of an external object with the Object Info node and plug it into a Transform Geometry node's Translation input and the result would be the same in both cases: the circle is now centered on the location (the origin) of the external object.

However, while a Mesh Circle generated inside Geometry Nodes will always be placed centered on the origin and this setup will always work with it, if the geometry comes from the Group Input, i.e. the base mesh, this could be moved offset from the origin point in Edit Mode and therefore the result will not be centered on the external object. Here a comparison where I show the base mesh in Edit Mode moved away from the origin and the result of both methods:

Of course by default the base mesh usually has its origin at its median point. But if this is not the case, you can do some Vector Math to counter that if you want both methods to get the same result.
You can plug whatever geometry you use into an Attribute Statistic node set to Vector and plug in a Position node. Then take the Median output and use a Vector Math > Subtract node to subtract this median position from the Location of the external object and use this for the translation.

